# Heroku - Error during git push/deployment, The same version of this code has already been built

Tags: java, git, github, heroku, heroku-cli

I have a problem deploying my springboot application to Heroku. After running `git push heroku master`, I am encountering the error below:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.350 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-22T06:33:14Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project audit: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :audit
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built:             31199a7acec03a3cb614ebaaf6c7720cee6684bd
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 31199a7acec03a3cb614ebaaf6c7720cee6684bd
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code     from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to tesda8app.
```

I am clueless into why this error occurred. I have two remote repositories on which I push my code, one from Heroku and one in Github. I have tried the command below based from the answer from this question, [Heroku: If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64265355/heroku-if-you-are-developing-on-a-branch-and-deploying-via-git-you-must-run)

```
git push heroku master:main
```

But still the error persists. Is there any command that I could try on the Heroku CLI to solve this problem?

Comment: That's just a warning. The actual error is above that. Please [edit] your question and show us the error messages above.

Comment: hi chris thank you for pointing that out. i already updated the error logs

Comment: I don't think that's the _whole_ message. Please add all of it.

Comment: hi @Chris ive updated the logs. that's all the error message i got

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some few tries, I was thinking that the cause of the problem was maybe an **interrupted** `git push heroku master` command, which was then proceeded by a re-execution of the same command, causing the error below:

```
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built:             31199a7acec03a3cb614ebaaf6c7720cee6684bd
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 31199a7acec03a3cb614ebaaf6c7720cee6684bd
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy         code     from a different branch.
remote:  !
```

So what I did was, I pushed another commit, then retried the same command `git push heroku master`, which resulted to a successful deployment.

Also, shoutout to [RainXCat's answer and insights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65436551/14806310), now I know Heroku does not allow two git repositories on the same directory/folder.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Adding another commit and push to the remote server solved my problem thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same error on the same day as you, I don't know if it's the answer you are looking for but I somehow solved the issue. I was making a Django-Rest-Api.

## **REASON**

you have created two git repositories in the same folder/directory and pushed the same code into their head and somehow **Heroku** doesn't want you to do that.
**remember no two git repo on the same level**.

### about the `git push heroku master:main` thing

Heroku only deploy your code from the main/master branch
so if you are pushing from other than master, you have to use it like `git push heroku <new branch>:main`, using `:main` with `master` is meaningless(same).

## SOLUTION

### option 1 (not working for me)

I don't remember exactly where I get this but you have to make a **new git branch**,
do

```
git branch <new branch>
git checkout <new branch>
git add .
git commit -am "commit message"
git push heroku <new branch>:main
```

but it's giving the same error because you still have two git repo in your directory.

you can remove the repo like this.

```
rm -rf .git
```

I suggest you to do the experiment on a temporary copy.

### option 2 (working for me)

**All I did was copy all the files inside, made a new folder with a different name, pasted all files, deleted the old, and rename the new to the old one. by doing this you will have a git free directory then you can use the `git init` method to simply make a new repo.**

#### here is how you should create

```
git init
heroku create
git add .
git commit -am "initial commit"
git push heroku master
```

This should resolve the error, It's solved for me so it's unlikely that I am going to work on it anymore but if my answer is not right in any manner please do tell me.

Answer (score 1):

I **deleted** my package-lock.json file and do the following again

1. git init
2. git add .
3. git commit -m ""
4. git push heroku main

the purpose is to clear your build cache

Answer (score 0):

**this worked for me!**

```html
git branch <new branch>
git checkout <new branch>
git add .
git commit -am "commit message"
git push heroku <new branch>:main

git push --set-upstream heroku <new branch>
```

> this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just made an empty commit and push again.
It worked for me.

```
git commit --allow-empty -m 'empty commit for pushing staging environment'
git push staging master
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by rebuilding the pipenv files:
`Pipfile`
`Pipfile.lock`

and released the newly added `conig.in` Pipfile is inconstant with the current Python version

Answer (score -1):

Install the Heroku CLI
Download and install the Heroku CLI.

If you haven't already, log in to your Heroku account and follow the prompts to create a new SSH public key.

```
$ heroku login
```

Clone the repository
Use Git to clone projects' source code to your local machine.

```
$ heroku git:clone -a project







$ cd project
```

Deploy your changes
Make some changes to the code you just cloned and deploy them to Heroku using Git.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```