# "Precompiling assets failed." error to push code from git hub repository to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Terminal throws "Precompiling assets failed." error to push code from github repository to heroku

[image]

How to push git-hub code from my git-hub repository to Heroku app?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post pictures of code or error messages. They are hard to read, and make it more difficult for people to help you. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65404309/heroku-error-during-git-push-deployment-the-same-version-of-this-code-has-alr) for possible help.

Comment: You're only showing the last few lines of error output. The useful stuff is above this.