# We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code, remote: ! at least twice

Tags: heroku

I found this error I tried log but couldn't find the solution, please let me know if anyone having the solution to this problem,
actually two repositories is crated how to remove one so my code push on Heroku server

```
 (tmenv) C:\Users\ok\Desktop\Django\Django_project\taskmate>git push heroku master
    Enumerating objects: 346, done.
    Counting objects: 100% (346/346), done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads
    Compressing objects: 100% (336/336), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (346/346), 1.50 MiB | 329.00 KiB/s, done.
    Total 346 (delta 58), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote:
    remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
    remote: -----> Using buildpack: Heroku/python
    remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
    remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
    remote:
    remote:!     Push failed
    remote:!
    remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: f6098f48382cfe82018384a09a28f785eb546aae
    remote:  !
    remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version f6098f48382cfe82018384a09a28f785eb546aae
    remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
    remote:  !
    remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
    remote:  !
    remote:! This article goes into details on the behavior:
    remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
    remote:
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote:
    remote:!       Push rejected to matetask.
    remote:
    To https://git.heroku.com/matetask.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/matetask.git'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku: If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64265355/heroku-if-you-are-developing-on-a-branch-and-deploying-via-git-you-must-run)

Comment: #1 are you using heroku git server or something like github? #2 Are you using several branches on heroku git or just the main or master branch? #3 Are you pushing to more than one remote from the same folder?

Comment: i am using heroku git server, 2. only using master branch , 3. may be I don't know actually I am beginner